# Best way to search for elements in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using innerHTML to get the inner HTML of an li element that is clicked. I would then like to search that HTML for some paragraph tags and find their value, is there a good way to do that? I can't rewrite any of the list's HTML, that's being generated elsewhere in the project but I do know the class names used for the

tags. jQuery answers are fine.

Comment: Have you tried a regular expression?

Comment: You could 'walk through' the childNodes to find the paragraphs or you could use the getElementsByTagName method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
// Attach onclick listener to li items of interest
$("your-li-selector").on('click', function () {
    // Select all p tags within the clicked element
    var pTags = $('p', this);

    // Iterate over all p tags
    pTags.each(function () {
         // Do search actions with `this.innerHtml` or `$(this).html()`
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to 'search' the HTML is to use the DOM. Note that if the container element in which you want to search exists in your DOM already, you do not need to contruct a new dummy element and can just retrieve this parent node and use the same approach.

```
var el = document.createElement('div'),
    someHtmlToSearch = '<div><p>test content in p</p></div>',
    pContent;

    el.innerHTML = someHtmlToSearch;
    pContent = el.querySelector('p').innerHTML; //search for the first p tag

console.log(pContent); //test content in p
```

Comment: To get all `p` tags under your `li` you should use `querySelectorAll()` instead. Note however, that the list is not live, and changes to the webpage will not appear in it.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that ahead of time that I won't know how many list elements are being created or there specific tag names (the list is generated using a database and so are some of the class name), in this case I do know the class names because I used innerHTML to find out what HTML is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").click(function(){
 var myPrag=this.innerHTML.find("p");
 });
```

Then use myParag

P.s. not tested

Comment: I think it's best to avoid a jQuery-dependent answer unless the OP specifies that they're using it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using jQuery to add the click listener, so jQuery answers would be fine.